# Minimum of a function given norm and scalar product in $L_2$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

This is a problem I encountered at a math competition for Master's students today, and so far nobody I know has any idea how to approach it. Decided I wanted to share it because I find it completely unobvious that the given constraints are enough to arrive at the answer.

Given $f\in C[-2,1]$ such that $\int\limits_{-2}^1f^2(x)dx=84,\ \int\limits_{-2}^1f(x)(2-x)dx=42$ find $\min\limits_{-2\leqslant x\leqslant 1} (x^2-f(x))$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let $g(x)=2-x$ and note that

$$
\|g\|_{L^2}^2=\int_{-2}^1 (2-x)^2\textrm{d}x=\int_{-2}^1 4+x^2-4x\textrm{d}x=12+\frac{1+8}{3}-2(1-4)=21
$$
Now, applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we see that
$$
42=|\langle f,g\rangle|\leq \|f\|_{L^2}\|g\|_{L^2}=\sqrt{84\cdot21}=\sqrt{2\cdot 42\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot 42}=42
$$
We only have equality in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality if $f=\alpha g$ almost surely for some appropriate $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$. Thus,
$$
42=\langle f,g\rangle=\alpha \|g\|_{L^2}^2,
$$
so $\alpha=2$.
Now, $f$ is assumed continuous, so $f(x)=2g(x)$ for every $x$. Now, it is completely elementary to see that 
\begin{align}
(x^2-f(x))'&=2(x+1)\\
(x^2-f(x))''&= 2,
\end{align}
so $x^2-f$ is convex and attains its minimum at $x=-1,$ so $$\min_{-2\leq x\leq 1} x^2-f(x)=(-1)^2-f(-1)=1-6=-5$$